# which function is faster push_back, insert in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to insert onto the end of a vector, 2 elements each time.

I was wondering whether doing vector.insert( iter_first, iter_second) is faster than doing vector.push_back( first ) then vector.push_back( second )?

Maybe another alternative would be to create a struct like this:

```
struct T{int a; int b;};
T t;
t.a = first;
t.b = second;
X.push_back(t);
```

Comment: You shouldn't structure your data based on what some guys say may be marginally faster. Use what makes sense. If these two values form logically belong together, chances are it makes sense as a struct, regardless of any potential performance implication.

Comment: Two `push_backs` seem to be at least twice as fast as one range insert at the back. No idea, why, probably the expense of setting up the array of two ints to be inserted.

Comment: @UncleBens - A push_back adds a constant number of elements at a known place. Optimizing that is much easier than inserting an unknown sequence of elements at a random position (which insert must be able to do).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the two elements are logically related, then you would use a struct or class. If they're unrelated then certainly don't group them for performance reasons.

This smells of premature optimization. Instead, write the code that's clearest to maintain and let the compiler generate the code for you. That's what it's there for. Consider that code that's easy to read is easy to maintain, and code that's easy to maintain is easy to refactor and less likely to have subtle performance bugs due to misunderstandings.

Answer (score 2):

While in your case the difference is insignificant, in general the C++ language standard specifies complexity information, so you don't need to ask - you can just look it up. [`vector::push_back` has amortized constant time complexity](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/push_back/), and [`vector::insert` is either proportional to the sum of the number of elements inserted and the number of elements moved, or the product of the two, depending on how you call it](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/insert/).

Answer (score 0):

Inserting at the end of a vector will be much faster than inserting at the middle or beginning of a vector.

This will only matter when you have a **Large** vector, and/or the copy constructors of your objects are **Incredibly** painful.

Answer (score 0):

Practically speaking, `push_back` will call `insert`, so calling
`push_back` twice ends up calling `insert` twice.  In practice, however,
if the code has been optimized, I'd be surprised if it made a
difference.  Do what's logical, and optimize later if you have
performance problems.